# Creating a Cocoapod library and [UIImage imageNamed:] returns NULL

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods

I have https://github.com/fulldecent/FDChessBoardView working great and am now starting the project again from scratch with `pod lib create` in order to make a Podspec.

There is one {'.h','.m'} file and some images. The images are in the file system in the provided Pod/Assets folder. The resources are noted in the podspec file with:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'FDChessboardView' => ['Pod/Assets/*']
}
```

(I have also tried directly adding these files into the `Development Pods/FDChessboardView/Resources` group inside XCode.)

Inside the library implementation file I need to refer to these images. I have tried:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FDChessboardView" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSString *imagePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"aa" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Here the imagePath is set correctly. This file exists and `file` confirms it is a PNG:

> [...]aa.png: PNG image data, 182 x 164, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

However the UIImage is NULL.

I have also tried these:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aa"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FDChessboardView.bundle/aa.png"];
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aa" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

All of them produce NULL.

Could anyone help point me in the correct direction for how to load theme image assets?

Thank you!

Will

Comment: Are you using an asset catalog in your bundle?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have spent far too long trying to solve the same issue...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok - I found a solution that works for me:

In the lib I am creating, I have the following class: `AEBubbleField.h` `AEBubbleView.m`

I also have an image in the `Assets` folder of the generated file structure called `background.png`. I want to use this in my lib files above so I add the following to the pod spec (to ensure the png is copied with my lib classes)

`s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'AEBubbleField' => 'Pod/Assets/*.png' }`

I can then access the image in the following manner:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]; // Any class in the lib can be used here, I just went for the current class
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

This is the only way I can get the image and use it. All other methods I have tried simply return `nil` like the original question's.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! The only thing I did different was `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`. My nightmare is over.

Comment: Nice! glad I could help - and thats a better approach so I will update my answer ;)

Comment: I wanted to add that in this case, the result of using frameworks requires resources to be accessed from the framework's bundle and not the `mainBundle`. There's some good reading [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/) that helped me understand what was happening.

Comment: Wish I could find this thread before... it perfectly applies to my issue too, which is slightly different: I found a similar approach as described here (http://t.co/LSAEc7BFiy),  which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

this answer works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324540/1897767

and, my swift code is:

```
class func loadImage(name: String) -> UIImage? {
    let podBundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)
    if let url = podBundle.URLForResource("MyBundleName", withExtension: "bundle") {
        let bundle = NSBundle(URL: url)
        return UIImage(named: name, inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rob's answer didn't work for me, I think because I didn't change the resource bundle setup from the default in `pod lib create`

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'PodCore' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png', 
                  'Pod/Classes/**/*.xib', 
                  'Pod/Classes/**/*.storyboard']
}
```

I was able to load images from that resource bundle, but had to define it explicitly.

```
NSString *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PodCore" 
                                                      ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundleURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_black.png" 
                            inBundle:podBundle
       compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

Comment: This answer should have way more upvotes, it was the only one working for me...
This was not working and bundle3 was nil:
`let bundle3 = Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.bundle")`
But with Brian's answer I got it working. Of course when I printed the bundleIdentifier I got
`org.cocoapods.bundle`... I really want to know why initialising the Bundle with the identifier returns nil to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift 2 > you can access this way:

```
// should access the bundle for this class
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
// successfully loaded image
let myImageToUse = UIImage(named: "image", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

Comment: That doesn't get the right `Bundle` in a pod library, that bundle is the main one, not the one with the pod resources.