# How to use images asset catalog in cocoapod library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I have a cocoapod library which contains assets in 2 formats:

- a .storyboard
- XCode asset catalog .xcassets (with images)

my `podspec` file contains the definition for the resource bundle:

```
s.resource_bundle = {'SparkSetup' => ['Resources/**/*.{xcassets,storyboard}']}
```

and I have a separate target in the pod project to create a resource bundle by using those files + a plist file for that bundle.

thing is that when I use the pod in an app project - I can see the storyboard/xcassets files being in the pod target and I can access and run the storyboard easily but the images referenced in the storyboard (to the .xcassets file) are not found in run-time (but displayed correctly in IB).

Error I get is:

```
Could not load the "spinner" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"
```

I do see a bundle file in the products directory.
To instanciate VCs in the storyboard I use:

```
+(NSBundle *)getResourcesBundle
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SparkSetup" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    return bundle;
}


+(UIStoryboard *)getSetupStoryboard
{
    UIStoryboard *setupStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"setup" bundle:[SparkSetupMainController getResourcesBundle]];
    return setupStoryboard;
}
```

which seems to work well for finding the storyboard, but not for finding images in the .xcassets in the same bundle.

What am I doing wrong? how can I reference images from this storyboard/from code and be able to integrate this UI pod into any app?

Thanks!

Comment: Having the exact same issue. I have noticed that if I used images without an asset catalogue it is working OK.

Comment: @bencallis apparently this is the only solution. XCode cannot seem to reference an asset catalog which is not loaded in main app bundle.. only solution is to change resource_bundle line in podspec to include `.png`s and not `.xcasset` and reference each image individually. not perfect but this is the only way it works..

Comment: Experiencing this issue as well. Can't even load images with imageNamed from an xcasset catalog inside the pod. :(

Answer (score 43):

At least as of version 1.0.1 of Cocoapods, image asset catalogs are supported.

In my **Swift 4.2** code, I used:

```
public static var GoogleIcon: UIImage {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
    log.msg("bundle: \(bundle)")
    return UIImage(named: "GoogleIcon", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
}
```

In my pod spec, I used:

```
s.resources = "SMCoreLib/Assets/*.xcassets"
```

When I build using the simulator, the .car file *does* show up in the Framework:

```
cd /Users/<snip>/SMCoreLib.framework 
ls
Assets.car  Info.plist  SMCoreLib
```

Comment: s.resources = "SMCoreLib/Assets/*.xcassets"

this saved my time , thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but this includes resources inside your application target not as part of Pod framework.

Comment: @MichK I'm not quite understanding what you are saying. AFAIK the image resources *do* get saved in the bundle for the Pod. Hence the need to use the NSBundle for the Pod as above.

Comment: @ChrisPrince what I mean is that by using `s.resources` you add resource files to main application bundle, but when you use  `s.resource_bundle` you add resource files to separate bundle which is then added to main application bundle. In my opinion second option gives better separation, but user of podspec can use both methods, depends on project specification and preferences.

Comment: @MichK This is the case only when integrating Pods statically. When use_frameworks! options is used, s.resources does the right thing and adds standard framework resources.

Comment: This worked great! However I needed a 'pod install' to get it working.

Comment: if your your project also has localization then it's like this: `s.resources = 'PodName/Resources/**/*.{strings,xcassets}'`

Answer (score 11):

Well, image asset catalogs are not supported via pods - just include a resource bundle that contains your image files in your podspec like so:

```
s.subspec 'Resources' do |resources|
    resources.resource_bundle = {'MyBundle' => ['Resources/**/*.{png}']}

end
```

and access the images safely from the pod like that:

```
+(NSBundle *)getResourcesBundle
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"MyBundle" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    return bundle;
}


+(UIImage *)loadImageFromResourceBundle:(NSString *)imageName
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [MyClass getResourcesBundle];
    NSString *imageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageName];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFileName inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    return image;
}
```

That solves all issues of handling images/resources within a cocoapod.

Comment: is it possible to get the images from storyboard as well this way?

Comment: @swalkner in storyboard you have to add ```MyBundleName.bundle/<imagename>.png``` in ```UIImageView``` image id, it will be available only in runtime. Not possibli to preview it.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using swift.

```
class func loadImage(name: String) -> UIImage? {
    let podBundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)
    if let url = podBundle.URLForResource("MyBundleName", withExtension: "bundle") {
        let bundle = NSBundle(URL: url)
        return UIImage(named: name, inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What is `MyClass` referred ?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 version**

```
private func getImageFromBundle(name: String) -> UIImage {
   let podBundle = Bundle(for: YourClass.self)
   if let url = podBundle.url(forResource: "YourClass", withExtension: "bundle") {
      let bundle = Bundle(url: url)
      return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
   }
   return UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Only this works for me (Swift 3 & Swift 4)**

```
public struct ImagesHelper {
  private static var podsBundle: Bundle {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: YourClass.self)
    return Bundle(url: bundle.url(forResource: "YourClass",
                                  withExtension: "bundle")!)!
  }

  private static func imageFor(name imageName: String) -> UIImage {
    return UIImage.init(named: imageName, in: podsBundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
  }

  public static var myImage: UIImage {
    return imageFor(name: "imageName")
  }
}
```

Then use it as below:

```
ImagesHelper.myImage
```

As in the [@Chris Prince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286446/3408316)'s answer, don't forget to update your podspec file like:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'YourClass' => ['YourPodName/*/Assets.xcassets']
}
```

Comment: setting s.resources and resource_bundles should work perfectly

Answer (score 4):

In you podspec do like this

```
s.resources = 'RootFolder/**/*.{lproj,storyboard,xcdatamodeld,xib,xcassets,json}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access images from pods by using their bundle id

[image]

```
 NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"bundle id of your pod"];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't still get it to work, with none of the solutions above.
I have an Assets.xcassets file in my Pod.

And inside my Pod classes i would like to access images from the Assets

Specified like this:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
     'SWDownloadPlayButton' => ['SWDownloadPlayButton/Assets/Assets.xcassets']
}
```

With this helper:

```
public struct ImagesHelper {
    private static var podsBundle: Bundle {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: SWDownloadPlayButton.self)
        return Bundle(url: bundle.url(forResource: "SWDownloadPlayButton",
                                      withExtension: "bundle")!)!
    }

    private static func imageFor(name imageName: String) -> UIImage {
        return UIImage.init(named: imageName, in: podsBundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
    }

    public static var download_icon: UIImage {
        return imageFor(name: "download_icon")
    }
}
```

But whatever i do inside my Pod classes (not in the example project)...like this

```
 var centerImage: UIImage = ImagesHelper.download_icon.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
    }
```

I still get a nil on the centerImage

Comment: Found it!! not working in property like this, but in de class init method it is working fine! All methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your `.xcassets` file within the resources in your pod spec, and use the following UIImage init:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(podAssetName: String) {
        let podBundle = Bundle(for: ConfettiView.self)

    /// A given class within your Pod framework
    guard let url = podBundle.url(forResource: "CryptoContribute",
                                  withExtension: "bundle") else {
        return nil

    }

    self.init(named: podAssetName,
              in: Bundle(url: url),
              compatibleWith: nil)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to the issue with CocoaPods. Instead of mucking with UIImage, I added a method to Bundle instead. The method attempts to locate an inner bundle of a given name, but falls back to the original bundle. This allows the code to work in both the application code using pods, as well as the pod code itself.

```
extension Bundle {

    /**
     Locate an inner Bundle generated from CocoaPod packaging.

     - parameter name: the name of the inner resource bundle. This should match the "s.resource_bundle" key or
       one of the "s.resoruce_bundles" keys from the podspec file that defines the CocoPod.
     - returns: the resource Bundle or `self` if resource bundle was not found
    */
    func podResource(name: String) -> Bundle {
        guard let bundleUrl = self.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "bundle") else { return self }
        return Bundle(url: bundleUrl) ?? self
    }
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` method or wherever else you have your image setting code, put something like this, where "ClassFromPod" refers to a Swift class from a CocoaPod, and "ResourceName" is the name of the inner bundle within the pod (you should be able to see the bundles using Xcode project navigator in "Pods/Projects" -- embedded bundles have a LEGO icon and have a "bundle" suffix.)

```
super.viewDidLoad()
let bundle = Bundle(for: ClassFromPod.self).podResource(name: "ResourceName")
img1 = UIImage(named: "FancyBase", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
img2 = UIImage(named: "FancyHandle", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

As you can see, the UIImage API remains the same, only the bundle being used is different depending on what it finds at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SwiftUI, using the `Image.init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle?)` initializer won't work, you have to initialize it like this:

```
 func getImage(named name: String) -> UIImage {
    // Use a random singleton class in your project.
    // Emphasis on class, structs won't work.
    let bundle = Bundle(for: [random class].self)

    if let image = UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil) {
        return image
    }

    return .init()
}
```

```
Image(uiImage: getImage(named: "image_name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining a bit all the answers and making it easy to copy-paste in your project:

```swift
class RandomClass: Any { } // Necessary for UIImage extension below
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(fromPodAssetName name: String) {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: RandomClass.self)
        self.init(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add your asset catalogs to your `.podspec` file:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
    'Resources' => ['YourPodName/*.xcassets']
}
```