# Access private asset catalog inside dependancy

Tags: ios, swift, assets

Im having a UI pod which needs to have its own directory for keeping image assets in it. Like `Images.xcassets` in every project, how can we make a separate one for dependancy only?. If possible how to access it from dependancy?

[image]

Comment: You can create another asset set with a different name and access it in the same way you are doing right now.

Comment: I have created a asset catalog named `Resources.xcassets` in pod directory as in above image. But the images inside it cannot able to access in default method.

Comment: As per the link posted above - image asset catalogs are not supported via pods - just include a resource bundle that contains your image files in your podspec

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: it's supported, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286446/1104384

Comment: Thank you i got it